# How to show maximum MenuItem on ActionBar if there is room...?

Tags: android

I'm facing problem dealing with `ActionBar`.

I have plenty of space on `ActionBar` but only two items are shown. Please tell me, if there is space, how to show all (maximum) `MenuItem`s on `ActionBar`? Also tell me how to display overflow menu button?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html
have a look at `Actionbar overflow` section. Number of icons in ActionBar depends on display width. For example if your display width is smaller than 360 dp you will be able to have max 2 items.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue.

What I did was create an `ActionBar` object then wrote:

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)
actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false)
```

This will clear up some room but didn't necessarily solve the problem.

The other thing you can do it in the xml file `android:showAsAction="always"` for each `MenuItem`.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a very delayed reply, but hope this will help someone.
Try giving the order for the items in your menu.xml

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:icon="@drawable/mytitle"
        android:orderInCategory="1"/>
```

It treats the order in ascending order